# Prioritize results sandwiched in tags

Tags: solr, solr-query-syntax

I have documents indexed like

```
{
"content":"Lots of text and some html",
"file_type": "application/pdf",
"id": "path_to_file",
"comp": "irrelevant fields",
"_version_": 1506272321148522231
}
```

I want Solr to prioritize the results that contain the queried keyword in `<abc>` and `</abc>` tags. How can this be done? I have searched a lot and didn't get any relevant answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to boost this at query-time using a Regex Query.

However, instead, I'd suggest parsing the innerText of `<abc>something</abc>` into it's own field at index-time (making it easy to boost at query-time).

This pre-processing can either be done by hand, or using the [PatternCaptureGroupFilterFactory](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.PatternCaptureGroupFilterFactory) in a custom analysis chain.